# Can´t install App on iPhone(Error: Could not locate device support files. )

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, updates

It seems like the latest version of IOS doesn´t fit with the current version of Xcode. When I try to install a test app on my iPhone, I get the error: This iPhone 6s is running iOS 11.2.2 (15C202), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode. 
Does someone know a solution?

Comment: Update your Xcode.

Comment: You need Xcode 9.2 for iOS 11.2.